# Why cancel occurs in API calls

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dependencies

In the parent component, open and setOpen state were passed to the child, and within useEffect, open was included as fetchData and dependency.
In the child component, open was added as a dependency to other fetchData within useEffect.
However, getApi() is being canceled in the child component.
If you declare open and setOpen state directly in the child component, it will work normally, but you must update the data with the parent's open dependency.

```
parent.tsx

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async() => {
  const res = await getPost();
  setPost(res);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [open]);

<Child open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
```

```
Child.tsx

const Child = ({open, setOpen}) => {

const [user, setUser] = useState();

const fetchData = async() => {
  const res = await getUser();
  setUser(res);
}

useEffect(() => {
fetchData();
}, [open]);

<button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Click</button>
{open && user && (
  <Modal onCancel={() => {setOpen(false) setUser(null} />
```

Comment: What is `getApi`?

Comment: Note that if the child changes the value of `open` via a call to `setOpen()` then then Parent will render twice and the Child will render 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

In the child component, the issue is caused by the **open** dependency in the **useEffect**. To prevent API calls from being canceled when **open** changes in the parent component, you can use a ref for **open**.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Child = ({ open, setOpen }) => {
  const userRef = useRef();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await getUser();
    userRef.current = res;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) setUser(userRef.current);
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Click</button>
      {open && user && (
        <Modal onCancel={() => { setOpen(false); setUser(null); }} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. If you use the parent component as is and use the code in the child component, an Unhandled Runtime Error occurs in getUser() when the parent component is rendered.
CanceledError: canceled This error occurs.